# how to get all string lines using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to take all string line between `EndOfSource.` and `EndOfMessage.`.

For example if output is:

```
8019 Warning Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client **EndOfSource.** The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs) for network adapter
with settings:

  Adapter Name : {B50403AE-8D65-4933-9E8E-7149657E41CD}

   Host Name : l-reg-8128

 Primary Domain Suffix : mtl.labs.mlnx

 DNS server list :

 10.7.77.135, 10.4.0.121

 Sent update to server : <?>

 IP Address(es) :

  fdfd:fdfd:7:36:2e0:81ff:fe33:92ad, 10.7.38.128

The reason the system could not register these RRs was because of a security related problem. The cause of this could be (a) your computer does not have permissions to register and update the specific DNS domain name set for this adapter, or (b) there might have been a problem negotiating valid credentials with the DNS server during the processing of the update request.

You can manually retry DNS registration of the network adapter and its settings by typing 'ipconfig /registerdns' at the command prompt. If problems still persist, contact your DNS server or network systems administrator. See event details for specific error code information. **EndOfMessage.**
```

I try the following code:

```
import re
re.findall("EndOfSource. (.*) EndOfMessage.", output)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: edited. please take a look

Comment: So, what is the problem? Try `re.findall(r"EndOfSource\. (.*?) EndOfMessage\.", output, flags=re.S)`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- The `.*` is a greedy subpattern, while you need the lazy one, use `.*?`
- The `.` does not match a newline by default, you need to enable a DOTALL mode with `re.S` or `re.DOTALL`
- Dots must be escaped to match literal dots.

Use

```
re.findall(r"EndOfSource\. (.*?) EndOfMessage\.", output, flags=re.S)
```